# How Can I Protect Encrypted Files From Being Corrupted Before Decryption

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, rijndael

I am encrypting a pdf file using the `Rijndael` algorithm. Encryption and decryption works fine. Encryption will convert the pdf file to a file with a `.key` extension.

The problem is that I am able to open this file in `notepad`(it shows some Unicode characters) and corrupt it. Consider the scenario that:

I have opened the file and **delete some characters/add Some characters** and `save the notepad file`. If I Passed this file to the Decryption method, I will get the corrupted file as output. I know this is happening because the byteStream gets varied(padding changed)while adding or deleting the characters in the file.

**Here is my question:**

Is there any way to overcome this issue? In other words, disable Editing to the encrypted file?**

Following is method am using for encryption,

**VB code**

```
   Dim plainFile As String = basePath & "\cryptoText.pdf"
   Dim password As String = "somePass"
   Dim UE As New UnicodeEncoding()
   Dim key As Byte() = UE.GetBytes(password)
   Dim cryptFile As String = basePath & "\cryptoText.key"
   Dim fsCrypt As New FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create)
   Dim RMCrypto As New RijndaelManaged()
   Using csKey As New CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
         Dim FsIn As New FileStream(plainFile, FileMode.Open)
         Dim data As Integer
         While (data = FsIn.ReadByte()) <> -1
                csKey.WriteByte(CByte(data))
         End While
         FsIn.Close()
    End Using
    fsCrypt.Close()
```

**C# code**

```
    string plainFile = basePath + "\\cryptoText.pdf";
    string password = "somePass";
    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
    string cryptFile = basePath + "\\cryptoText.key";
    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);
    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
    using (CryptoStream csKey = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
        FileStream FsIn = new FileStream(plainFile, FileMode.Open);
        int data = 0;
        while ((data == FsIn.ReadByte()) != -1) {
            csKey.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(data));
        }
        FsIn.Close();
    }
    fsCrypt.Close();
```

**note:** i have tried it both in c# and vb.net so that am tagging my question to both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is do two things,

1. Encrypt,
2. Add an HMAC to it (like SHA256 using same key), on the encrypted data, and tack it to the end of the cryptostream

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Then when you decrypt, you

1. Verify that HMAC is valid,
2. IFF #1 verifies, then and only then decrypt

Furthermore, if this is not local files but some sort of network stream, then you have to do verification in constant time - you can't use normal byte comparison functions. This is because of timing attacks. But for local files, you can do whatever comparison you like since there is no timing attacks.

Comment: Note that this *doesn't* protect the files against being corrupted, it just detects the corrupted files so you can act upon it. This is basically the difference between "tamper-evident" vs "tamper-resistant". The way to be "tamper-resistant" is to disallow write access to the file.

Comment: Beware that the above scheme is not yet protected against replay attacks (this comment and the comment above do not invalidate the answer, they just add security related information to it).

Answer (score 3):

You can't really prevent anyone from opening the file in whatever editor they please and modifying it. Marking the file as read only might help a little but will not solve the problem.

What you should do instead is generate a hash of the encrypted file and then before decrypting it check to make sure that the file still generates the same hash. If it does not, you know that the file has been tampered with.

Comment: @un-lucky see the other answer :)

Comment: The other answer would require you to store a (static) HMAC key and an authentication tag for (or in) the file. This answer would require you to store the hash of the file (separately from the file) before it can be tampered. So I don't think these answers are identical in that sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes True.